# R Function which computes 10-fold cross-validation MSE errors

Tags: r, cross-validation, splines

There is some data I want to fit B-splines to and I already have a scheme for the location of the knots, but I want to use cross-validation to find the optimal number of knots. Is there any built-in R function (or external package) I can use for this rather than coding it by myself?